# Identify latest records from multiple tables and join them all together

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-tables

I have 5 related tables I am trying to produce a query teport from.

What would be the process by which this can be achieved?

The end result should be:

| Last Calving_Date | Latest EC_Date | Latest BScore | Latest Group | Cow ID | 19-Jul-21 | 12-Jul-21 | 5-Jul-21 | 28-Jun-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21/07/2021 | 15/12/2021 | 3 | RED | 18415 | 21 | 25 | 24 | 22 |
| 02/06/2021 | 11/11/2021 | 3.5 | RED | 18413 | 30 | 25 | 24 | 22 |
| 10/05/2021 | 15/10/2021 | 2.5 | YELLOW | 18419 | 27 | 25 | 26 | 21 |

At least 1 of the Week1... Week4 columns should have a value from Prod List.
The table is sorted based on Last Calving_Date descending order.

The tables are:

Add_Cow_Event

| Calving_Date | Cow ID | Event Type | UID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21/07/2021 | 18415 | Calved | 100000001 |
| 10/05/2021 | 18419 | Calved | 100000002 |
| 11/06/2020 | 18415 | Calved | 100000003 |

PREGNANCY REGISTER

| EC_DATE | Cow ID | UID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15/12/2021 | 18415 | EC100000001 |
| 15/10/2021 | 18419 | EC100000002 |
| 11/06/2020 | 18415 | EC100000003 |

Animal Register

| Cow ID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 18415 | Active |
| 18419 | Active |
| 18413 | Active |

Body Scoring Table

| Date | Cow ID | BScore | BS_UID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21/07/2021 | 18415 | 3 | BS1023 |
| 10/05/2021 | 18419 | 2.5 | BS1024 |
| 11/06/2020 | 18415 | 3.5 | BS1025 |

Feed Groups

| Date | Cow ID | Color | GC_UID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21/07/2021 | 18415 | RED | GC103 |
| 10/05/2021 | 18419 | YELLOW | GC104 |
| 11/06/2020 | 18415 | BLUE | GC105 |

PRODUCTION TABLE

| Date | Cow ID | Shift |  | Production |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19/07/2021 | 18415 | MORN | 5 | P103 |
| 19/07/2021 | 18415 | NOON | 5 | P104 |
| 19/07/2021 | 18415 | NIGHT | 5 | P105 |
| 19/07/2021 | 18419 | MORN | 10 | P106 |
| 19/07/2021 | 18419 | NOON | 11 | P107 |
| 19/07/2021 | 18419 | NIGHT | 6 | P108 |
| 12/07/2021 | 18415 | MORN | 8 | P109 |
| 12/07/2021 | 18415 | NOON | 12 | P110 |
| 12/07/2021 | 18415 | NIGHT | 3 | P111 |

My first step was to try and produce a table of the Latest Calving Dates using the below query:

```
SELECT
         Add_Cow_Event.Calving_Date,
         Add_Cow_Event.Event Type,
         Animal Register.Animal ID,
FROM  Add_Cow_Event
LEFT JOIN Animal Register ON Add_Cow_Event.CowID  = Animal Register.Animal ID  
WHERE    Add_Cow_Event.Event Type  = 'Calved'
ORDER BY Add_Cow_Event.Calving_Date DESC
```

This produces

| Calving_Date | Cow ID | Event Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21/07/2021 | 18415 | Calved |
| 10/05/2021 | 18419 | Calved |
| 11/06/2020 | 18415 | Calved |

Next, I need to find the latest Calving Date for every Cow ID and remove the older records from the table. How could this be achieved?

Comment: When several tables are involved, it's good programming practice to qualify _all_ columns. Like  `Add_Cow_Event.Calving_Date` instead of just `"Event Type`.

Comment: Tip: Table aliases save you some typing, and makes the code easier to read! `...FROM  Add_Cow_Event ace
LEFT JOIN Animal_Register ar ON ace.CowID  = ar.Animal ID...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for ROW_NUMBER() with partition by and pick only the latest record for the cow as given below:

```sql
SELECT Calving_Date, Animal_ID as Cow_ID, Event_Type
FROM
(SELECT
         Add_Cow_Event.Calving_Date,
         Add_Cow_Event.Event_Type,
         Animal Register.Animal_ID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Animal_ID ORDER BY calving_Date Desc) AS Rnk
FROM  Add_Cow_Event
LEFT JOIN Animal_Register ON Add_Cow_Event.CowID  = Animal_Register.Animal_ID  
WHERE    Add_Cow_Event.Event Type  = 'Calved') AS t
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thank you @Venkataraman R. With the above code I have been able to Consolidate all the Latest Values for a number of columns for each cow.

Comment: @GertVanHel, Glad to note. As it has helped you to address your issue, please mark it as answer, by clicking the tick mark. It will be helpful for others in future.

Comment: Will do. Could you possible advise regarding a last hurdle of fine? I have one final table I am struggling to summarize. It is the Production Table. I need to aggregate production per COW ID per day as there are 3 shifts per day in the data. Then I need to display each day's production in a separate column next to the CowID to compare production between those days. Once this table is produced I should be able to do a FULL OUTER JOIN between it and the current table with all the other attributes I have consolidated.

Comment: @GertVanHel, please ask it as separate question. changing the question and answer will lead to confusion for future users.